# $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} < +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ f: \mathbb N  \to \mathbb N$ be a bijective function such that:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} < +\infty$$

Now my question is does any such $f$ exists?

Comment: $f(n) = n$ will certainly work

Comment: @Joppy $f(n)=n$ certainly does not work.

Comment: No @Joppy . $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $ is divergent

Comment: @PierreCarre: whoops!

Comment: I don't know if this works but in the finite case, i.e. bijective $f:\{1,2,...,n\}\to\{1,2,...,n\},S=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(k)}{k^2}$ attains the minimum value when $f(k)=k$. So as $n\to\infty$ we have $S\ge\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{k^2}\to\infty$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Since the sequence of partial sums is divergent, the infinite sum must be divergent as well.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Your argument is ok. What you are able to conclude for the partial sums extends to the series. You should convert the comment into an answer.

Comment: @lonestudent That is not bijective

Comment: @Shubham yes I missed.

Comment: @Tan: but what if $\sum_{n_j}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n_j} < +\infty$ with $n_j$ satisfy the condtion $ f{(n_j)} \ge n_j$

Comment: @NN2 Yes I noticed that and deleted the comment, but I still wonder how can it be shown that there are infinitely many $n_i$'s such that $f(n_i) \geq n_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be any given bijection from $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$. Consider the partial sum $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(k)}{k^2}$. Suppose $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a strictly increasing sequence such that $t_i\in f(\{1,2,...,n\})$. Clearly, $t_i\ge i$. Then, from the rearrangement inequality$$S_n\ge\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{t_i}{i^2}\ge\sum_{i=1}^n\frac i{i^2}$$

Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac i{i^2}\to\infty$.

Comment: I think you should mention that if $f$ attains values greater than $n$, then its sum increases. Also, do you think argument would work with just injectivity instead of bijectivity?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. The hard part of the initial problem lies on the 2 following statements: First statement, the one you mentionned:  $S_n$  is minimum when the smallest $i∈\{1,2,...,n\}$ is assigned to the largest term $1/i^2$ and so on". Second statement: you can generate the 1st statement to $n=+\infty$

Comment: This is not rigorous. You can't take the limit to $n\to\infty$ for some function which was defined for just $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ to make it a function defined on $\mathbb N$. See my answer for a rigorous treatment of the partial sums.

Comment: To make it rigorous, you need to note that $$ \inf_{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k)}{k^2} \ge  \inf_{f:\{1\dots n\}\rightarrow \{1\dots n\}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k)}{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} $$
Only after that you can take limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you only consider bijections which permute $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and fix $n+1, n+2, \ldots$ and take the limit, then the resulting argument is only valid for such bijections. There are many more bijections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ than those that are eventually constant.

Comment: @NN2 Is this ok?

Comment: Your solution presented the idea of the proof but it's not complete yet. You can look at the comment of Joppy or Martund  for more details. Besides, as the question was already well answered here  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2026313/195378

Answer (score 0):

Define $$g(m)=\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{f(n)}{n^2}$$
Now note that if the $f$-image of the set $[m]=\{1,2,\dots, m\}$ is $[m]$ itself, then the minimum value of $g(m)$ is taken when $f(k)=k\:\forall\:1\le k\le m$ (by rearrangement inequality).

Otherwise there exists a subset $S$ of $[m]$ such that $f(S)\subset[m]$ and $f([m]\setminus S)\cap[m]=\emptyset$. In this case, we may note that $g(m)$ is term-wise more than or equal to the partial sum obtained by replacing $f([m]\setminus S)$ by $[m]\setminus f(S)$ and if we do that, the lower bound obtained above using rearrangement inequality again applies. Therefore, we have,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{f(n)}{n^2} =\lim_{m\to\infty}g(m)\ge\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^m\dfrac1n=\infty
\end{equation}
Hence, this series is divergent.

Comment: @NN2, Edited it.

Comment: As you modiftied your answer, I withdraw then my first comment.