# Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be bijection such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2}< \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be bijection such that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2}< \infty$$

Then numbers of such bijections is zero, or one or finitely many but more than one or infinite such bijections.

I think there will be no such bijection . Am i right ? if yes how to prove that ? any hint

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:complex-analysis]?

Comment: "Then numbers of such bijections is zero, or one or finitely many but more than one or infinite such bijections." - what does this mean? I can't parse it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams How many choices of $f$ that are bijections are there that satisfy the relation?

Comment: @DonThousand ah that makes much more sense. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Also asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4030456/42969

Answer (score 3):

There is no such $f$. Indeed, for every $N$, you have
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^{3N} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} \geq \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N} \frac{f(n)}{(3N)^2} \geq \frac{N^2}{9N^2}$$

because the $f(n)$ for $n \in [N+1, 3N]$ are $2N$ distinct integers, so at least $N$ of them are greater than $N$.

So
$$\sum_{N+1}^{3N} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} \geq \frac{1}{9}$$

so the series is not Cauchy, so it diverges.

Comment: That is a nice argument (you may consider to answer the original question, instead of this one which is already closed). Note that the last expression in the first equation should be $N^2/(3 N)^2 = N^2/(9 N^2)$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thanks ! I edited the typo, and will add this answer to the original question.